# Heroku failed to serve django admin static files - other static files work

Tags: django, heroku

I'm having trouble serving django admin static files from Heroku.

Receiving 404 error for /static/admin/css/base.css - I have the same dir structure and the file base.css is inside it.

Non admin static files work great

This is how I serve static files:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True})
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Neither of those will work at all, because Django itself does not serve static files when DEBUG is False. You should use Whitenoise, as well described in the Heroku docs for using Django.

Comment: do load static before deploying

Comment: this works for non admin files.

Comment: Are you run collectstatic command?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
It was related to Cloudflare caching, I disable cache in the browser and everything works as expected.